# Accumulation of Draw Calls in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am creating a drawing application using metal in iOS. I am passing the touched points to shader to draw squares. The drawing calls are accumulating when touched points increases.

How to reduce all draw calls buffer to single draw calls even though touch points increases.

I add sample current drawing calls accumulating picture[image]

Because of this draw call accumulation. Same resources are wastely accumulating. For example with every draw calls i am passing textures of brushes are acculating.

Comment: Use instanced rendering and store only the values that vary per-point in a separate buffer that grows as you add more touch points.

Comment: @warrenm thanks. It worked  https://imgur.com/gallery/zJZrLXQ